# How do I remove social buttons from the "Blog" section of my theme?

Tags: social-sharing, sharing

I have a specific question about the blog section of my site. It is located here: www.newangleanalytics.com/blog

If you click on the article, you will notice three social media button at the bottom. Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest. The problem is, I don't know where they are in the admin section and I've tried everywhere! I already found a plugin that easily gave me the share buttons, so I don't need those three. But I can't figure out how to remove it. All tutorials show how to remove social buttons from your MAIN PAGE, not from your blog, so I'm a little stuck. Any insight is appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Alper, please contact your theme's developers for support. Questions about third party plugins and themes are off topic here on WPSE. You can read more about what kinds of questions are on-topic [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: No problem. I'll see if I can find contact info on theme developer. Sorry for posting on the wrong area and thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the social icons using CSS:

```
 .single-post .share-page { display: none; }
```

The CSS should be added using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to ensure that the changes are not lost when the parent theme is updated.

Comment: ...or you can add the CSS in the theme's Additional CSS settings under Theme, Customize. If the theme doesn't have that, there are plugins that will add that setting to the Theme's Customize menu. For this little change, a Child Theme is not needed.